# Can't figure out why my PHP isn't inserting in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data from simple register form into MySQL. I have my db hosted on Amazon AWS RDS, using DBeaver to edit it. When I run the code I get the following

> affected_rows." data inserted into database."; } else { echo "An
>   error has occurred. The items were not added."; } $db->close(); ?>

How do i fix this? Is my PHP wrong? I'm confused whether or not I can use MySQLi, how would i determine that? I'm assuming Amazon RDS MySQL is compatible.

```
<?php
// create short variable names
$name=$_POST['name'];
$birthdate=$_POST['birthdate'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city+$_POST['city'];

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $name = addcslashes($name);
    $birthdate = addslashes($birthdate);
    $email = addcslashes($email);
    $password = addcslashes($password);
    $address = addcslashes($address);
    $city = addcslashes($city);
}

$host='xxxxxx'
$user='admin'
$password='xxxxx'
$dbname='users'
@ $db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: Could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

// Execute the query
$query = "INSERT INTO vestorinfo (name,birthdate,email,password,address,city)
    VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[birthdate]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[city]')";
$result = mysqli_query($query)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query."};

if ($result) {
    echo $db->affected_rows." data inserted into database.";
} else {
    echo "An error has occurred. The items were not added.";
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Here is the form from the html page

```
    <div id="registerform">
    <form action="php/registerprocess.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="birthdate">Birth Date</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="birthdate" name="birthdate" placeholder="07/04/1950" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
    <span class="help-block">Must be &gt;= 8 characters including at least 1 number</span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Address</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">City</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="city" name="city" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: It looks like your PHP isn't running and why not echo out the real error?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This will fix any pesky quoting issues you may be having. Also check for mysqli errors along the way.

Comment: `$city+$_POST['city'];` should be `$city=$_POST['city'];`  Also after having set all these values, why do you fall back to using the $_POST values in your insert?

Comment: Aside from the already mentioned issues `mysqli_query` won't work with just a query, you need to pass in the connection object as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Would this be happening cause Im running the file locally off my pc instead of off the server?

Comment: Only if you're not running some sort of server on your PC. If you just open the PHP file in your browser, then yes, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is at risk for sql injection and you should use param binding  instead of var as $_POST 
anyway respect to you question the missing insert values 
could be because are related  to the fact you are referring to the index  of $_POST in  wrong way

eg : using a concatenation  you should

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO vestorinfo (name,birthdate,email,password,address,city)
      VALUES ('" . $_POST['name'] ." , " . $_POST['birthdate'] .", " . 
      $_POST['email'] . "," . $_POST['password'] . "," .
         $_POST['address'] . "," . $_POST['city'] . ")";
```

Comment: There are numerous other issues though, such as the PHP not even being executed.

Comment: @chris85   . could be . I gave just a first glimpse.

Comment: I'd like to at least get the PHP to execute before I start handling the injection issues

Comment: if for this that i have posted  my answer .. once you have undertsand why don't work you can improve the code for sql injection  .. but is important remember  this